# Generate from WSDL is failing

Tags: wsdl

I am trying to generate Apex class from WSDL file but I am getting below error: "Unsupported WSDL. Found more than one part for message AWDProcessingService_retrieveObjects".

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you able to share the WSDL in question?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at one of previous answers

[Importing UPS Street Address WSDL into Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4000/importing-ups-street-address-wsdl-into-apex)

You will have to edit your WSDL as explained.Wrap your parts definition with message and some changes in header as suggested above