# Importing Wsdl2Apex with multiple wsdl:part in a wsdl:message

Tags: soap-api, callout, soap, wsdl2apex, apex-webservice

I am trying to import a WSDL in salesforce which contains Multi-part messages.

Multi-part messages are not supported by the wsdl2Apex tool. The suggested [workaround](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4003/69764) is to modify the WSDL to generate an apex class and keeping the request-response XML structure the same.

I tried starting with the `embeddedAsync.init` method where I added an extra class to wrap all the parts messages. however, the callout fails with an exception

```
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Unexpected element {http://webservice.embedded.server.qa.encoway.com/}init found. Expected {http://webservice.embedded.server.qa.encoway.com/}WebserviceSessionId. faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=
```

I am new to the SOAP API world and would like to understand how the multipart WSDL be consumed in apex.

A simple example would be of great help.

Here are the WSDL and the generated code in which I modified `embeddedAsync.init` method: [Sample Code](https://gist.github.com/anmolgkv/bf9bd0acdc6924982397a8e9e28c89f8)

Comment: You might want to show with WSDL examples that you tried the mentioned workaround and failed with another issue. Otherwise, I fear that eager moderators will close this a "duplicate".

Comment: Its a really big WSDL and generated apex code, I have linked it as a gist: https://gist.github.com/anmolgkv/bf9bd0acdc6924982397a8e9e28c89f8

Comment: Doesn't Daniel Balinger's FuseIT tool overcome this issue?

Comment: I tried the FuseIT explorer app as well, got the same error while parsing WSDL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you are going to be able to use wsdl2apex and the corresponding `WebServiceCallout.invoke()` to call these multipart methods.

As you have observed, the `init` message is comprised of 4 parts:

1. sessionId
2. taskId
3. initContext
4. callbackContext

But `WebServiceCallout.invoke()` will only accept a single request parameter as the second argument.

You might be able to promote all but one of the parts into headers as per [Importing UPS Street Address WSDL into Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4003/102), but that would depend on what the target web service is expecting.

---

There are a couple of challenges with this [WSDL](https://gist.github.com/anmolgkv/bf9bd0acdc6924982397a8e9e28c89f8#file-wsdl-xml):

1. The `schema` defines a `targetNamespace`, but omits the `xmlns` attribute.
2. There are several elements in the schema that are defined as complex types that have a nested element also defined by a complex type. E.g. `AsyncActivateResult > activateResult`.

(1) was easily resolved by adding an `xmlns` attribute on the schema to match the targetNamespace.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.embedded.server.qa.backend.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" 
            targetNamespace="http://webservice.embedded.server.qa.backend.com/" 
            xmlns="http://webservice.embedded.server.qa.backend.com/" 
            version="1.0">
```

(2) was resolved by extracting the nested complexType elements are promoting them to direct descendants of the schema. Then the elements use the resulting type as a reference rather than trying to nest the complexType.

```
<!-- Created this complex type from the content of activateResult -->
<xs:complexType name="activateResultType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="tns:SaveResultType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="printedDocument" type="tns:ActivationAttachment"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="exportFormat" type="tns:ActivationAttachment"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="AsyncActivateResult">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="phase" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="activateResult" type="activateResultType">
                <!--<xs:complexType> has been un-nested -->
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The resulting Apex class - [webserviceEmbeddedServerQaBackendCo.cls](https://gist.github.com/FishOfPrey/6a32b7c12794b2905fadcbf9f7f96cd0)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10598098/4019177 which suggests Wrapping multiple parts in a single document. I believe this will solve the issue but would need some change in the backend